# Using jQuery to change image src when browser is resized

Tags: jquery, image, replace, screen-size, window-resize

I have two different sized images, one if for screens smaller than 759px, the other is for screens larger than 759px.

I have managed to get the source of the images to change when the document loads depending on the window width. But I really would like to be able to do this when the browser is resized as well but for the life of me I can't get it to do that, it only seems to work when the page is initially loaded.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function imageresize() {
        var contentwidth = $(window).width();
        if ((contentwidth) < '700'){
            $('.fluidimage').each(function(){
                var thisImg = $(this);
                var newSrc = thisImg.attr('src').replace('x2', 'x1');
                thisImg.attr('src', newSrc);
            });
        } else {
            $('.fluidimage').each(function(){
                var thisImg = $(this);
                var newSrc = thisImg.attr('src').replace('x1', 'x2');
                thisImg.attr('src', newSrc);
            });
        }
    }

    imageresize();//Triggers when document first loads

    $(window).bind("resize", function(){//Adjusts image when browser resized
        imageresize();
    });
 });
```

Comment: I tried this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GqQsr/1/) and it changed src of image on resizing. _Did I miss something?_ What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I have tested // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(imageresize); in jsFiddle and it works as expected...

Comment: Just a hint: using .each on window resize is extremely cpu consuming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try this...

change your follwoing line of code

```
$(window).bind("resize", function(){//Adjusts image when browser resized
        imageresize();
    });
```

to

```
// Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(imageresize);
```

and put alert inside imageresize to see if it works or not...

In case above do not work out...I believe there is one problem probably..

in your code you have

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(window).bind("resize", function(){//Adjusts image when browser resized
        imageresize();
    });
}
```

So the function for reside inside jquery which may not work well. On top of that try using simple javascript;  i had similar problem and solved using plain javascript and jquery did not work in some browsers.

Sound strange enough to stop you try at it but would work...

Answer (score 4):

Try to use css3 media queries instead of doing it in jQuery or javascript.

http://css-tricks.com/media-queries-sass-3-2-and-codekit/

Consider using "img-src" class on a . Whenever the screen is resized b/w 600px to 900px; x2.jpg will be loaded. By default x1.jpg will be used.

Ex:

```
.img-src {
   background-image: url("http://imageurlhere.com/x1.jpg");
}


@media (min-device-width:600px) and (max-width:900px) {
  .img-src {
      background-image: url("http://imageurlhere.com/x2.jpg");
   }
}
```

Comment: Though CSS3 is indeed very handy for this stuff; for the sake of browser compatibility (e.g. non CCSS3 compatible browsers), I'd recommend doing it in jQuery.

Comment: Also the OP might want the image to be an actual img tag with src instead of a background image.

Comment: @Simon, The underlying concept is to flip images based on window size. what i gave is an example of using media queries for this scenario. i just showed the route map, not exact answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not jQuery but you can simple use `document.getElementById("myId").src="another.jpg";` to define the new src of the img with id "myId".

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, as I can see, but I prefer to use `setTimeout`, some times page could slow down without resize pause.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var resizeTimer,
        $window = $(window);

    function imageresize()
    {
        if ($window.width() < 700)
        {
            $('.fluidimage').text('< 700');
        }
        else
        {
            $('.fluidimage').text('>= 700');
        }
    }
    imageresize();//Triggers when document first loads

    $window.resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(imageresize, 100);
    });
 });
```

Example: [jsfiddle.net/SAbsG/](http://jsfiddle.net/SAbsG/)