# Faster way to run this resize script

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#content-wrapper').height($(window).height() - $('#header-wrapper').height() - 25);
});

$(window).resize(function(e) {
    $('#content-wrapper').height($(window).height() - $('#header-wrapper').height() - 25);
});
```

Something tells me I'm doing it either wrong or taking a longer route.

Is there a faster way to recreate the exact same script?

Footnote: For those with a minor case of OCD, this scrip resizes a `<div>` to make it fill the rest of the page. The height of `#header-wrapper` is random and the 25 is the padding between the `#header-wrapper` and the `#content-wrapper`.

Comment: Not going to make it faster, but first, I would refactor those two identical anonymous functions into one named function.

Comment: You could store the `$('#header-wrapper').height() - 25` in a global variable if that shouldn't change. I would think that's static, but I don't know the page! You'd have to do that in document.ready

Comment: It's because resize fires MANY times while you resize the window, not just when you complete the resize.  See my answer below

Comment: i like CDO better, it's like OCD but the letters are sorted properly >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I would think is related to resize firing many times WHILE you are resizing, and not just at completion.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/8kaar/

To remedy this, add a setTimeout, and clear it on resize, so it only executes after you stop resizing

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kaar/1/

So your code should change to

```
$(window).ready(resizeCallback);
$(window).resize(resizeCallback);

var resizeTimeoutId = null;
function resizeCallback() {
    if (resizeTimeoutId)
        window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeoutId);

    resizeTimeoutId = window.setTimeout(resizeAction, 250);
}

function resizeAction() {
    $('#content-wrapper').height($(window).height() - $('#header-wrapper').height() - 25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the #header-wrapper size change after page load? if not, then you dont need to be recalculating the height each time you resize the window, which will speed things up.

Comment: I think the point is that it needs to be done on window resize, because if the window resizes, the div, "content-wrapper", needs to be resized to fit the new shape of the window...

Answer (score 0):

First of all your solution is slower, because you finding DOM elements on each resize and wrap them to jquery object, you need `cache` them. Look at my example from this question: [resize example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471882/using-jquery-to-change-image-src-when-browser-is-resized)

Comment: He's finding two items by id though, it should be a negligible difference in speed.

Comment: "CaffGeek  It depends on many factors, such as the page size and etc. How many times function will be called while I will resize the window?