# jQuery: how to change default image and hover image when screen size is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an external CSS file for responsive elements on page:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1089px){
   #shipping a{float:left;width:100%;margin-top:7px;padding:10px 0 10px 0;background:url("/images/shared/resp1.png") no-repeat;}
   #shipping a:hover{float:left;margin-top:7px;padding:10px 0 10px 0;background:url("/images/shared/h-resp1.png") no-repeat;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1011px){
   #shipping a{float:left;width:100%;margin-top:7px;padding:10px 0 10px 0;background:url("/images/shared/resp2.png") no-repeat;}
   #shipping a:hover{float:left;margin-top:7px;padding:10px 0 10px 0;background:url("/images/shared/h-resp2.png") no-repeat;}
}
```

I need to removed the external CSS file and use jQuery instead to replace the image.

I have found solutions to replace an image using jQuery that other users have posted, like: [Using jQuery to change image src when browser is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471882/using-jquery-to-change-image-src-when-browser-is-resized)

But I am unsure following that example, how the hover image can also be included, as well as the other properties such as float, width, margin, that are in the CSS file.

How do I replace the default image, and the hover image, along with the other CSS properties using jQuery?

Comment: You can change CSS properties with jQuery but it's quite a bit more work, especially if you're doing it based on screen size. Why do you need to use jQuery instead of CSS?

Comment: Any question asked like this "Is it possible to ... X?" the answer will be either yes or no.  You should ask "How do I ... X?" instead.

Comment: To APAD1, I was using the CSS above, but responsive elements/ design does not work on IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

The general approach for this is going to need to be something along the lines of:

An event listener using `$(window).resize() which can then adjust the CSS using`$('#some-element-id').css('property-name','value')` and the image source (which you say you already know how to do depending on a condition along the lines of

```
if($(window).width() < x){
...
```

Regarding the hover feature, if you are planning on doing this using JQuery, consider using a variable to store the path to the hover image which can be updated in your `resize`event listener above and then create an event listener for the hover event on your image using the same kind code as when you changed the main source of the image but just referring to the variable you create.

Ok?